# Why does pandas.dataframe generate random order

Tags: python, pandas

Why does

> df = pd.DataFrame({user, points, timestr})

in

```
import pandas as pd
import time
timestr = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

url_all_time = 'https://community.koodomobile.com/widget/pointsLeaderboard?period=allTime&maxResults=20&excludeRoles='
data = pd.read_json(url_all_time)
user = data['name'][0]
points = data['points'][0]
df = pd.DataFrame({user, points, timestr})
# df = df.transpose()
df.to_csv('products.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Generate random order results? Why does it not follow user, points, timestr? Sometimes names is first, sometimes it's the time, sometimes it's points? Did I not understand how pd.df works?

Comment: Because `{user, points, timestr}` is a `set`, and `set` objects have arbitrary order. If you want a container type that preserves order, use a list or tuple.

Comment: Anyway to make it non arbitrary?

Answer (score 0):

The code `{user, points, timestr}` creates a `set` of those three objects. Set objects are arbitrarily ordered, which is why you are seeing different orders with different runs. To  preserve order, use a list or tuple.

```
# list
pd.DataFrame([user, points, timestr])
# tuple
pd.DataFrame((user, points, timestr))
```

Comment: I ended up doing
idata= (user, points, timestr)
df = pd.DataFrame(idata)

Comment: Great. That creates a tuple, which is similar to the second solution in my answer.